# How to display only category of blog without custom code?

Tags: categories

Is it possible to display the titles of a category without having to use custom code or plugins?

I'd like to use two or three categories (basically two or three blogs) on the same site.

Comment: a category archive should work. for more flexibility, have you considered to use category templates?

Answer (score 0):

Have you use [wp_list_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) function? It will help you show a list of categories easily!

Comment: I was looking for something that doesn't require custom coding.  Are there any examples of this function being implemented?